# Tampermonkey, waiting for value to be set in another tab os it can be read

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, setvalue, getvalue

I have a userscript that opens another tab, where it runs too.

I use GM_setvalue and GM_getvalue to exchange a value between them.

In the main tab, I want to halt the execution of the code until the value is updated from the other tab.

My first and so far the closest try was when I added a while() loop with an empty command to check for the stored value, if it still has its default value set. My code does change the stored value in the other tab, but in the main tab the code is still stuck in the loop. For which, I do not see the reason.

Could you please help me?

Regards,
polarka

Comment: Is that other tab on the same domain? By *I have a userscript that opens another tab*, do you use `window.open` to open the new tab?

Comment: I use GM_openInTab(). Sorry, I was not expecting a response this fast.

Comment: Use `GM_addValueChangeListener`, look for examples yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Now I must sleep.

Comment: So, I made the changes on my script to implement the EventListener. With events, it works, thank you.

Comment: Though, I faced a problem: I open multiple tabs, I save information from those to values and change a value that acts as a counter, then I close the tabs. I added a listener to that counter and was checking it in the Listener's function if the counter reaches 0. When it does I wanted to collect those values from the tabs. But unfortunately my counter decreases only once and not every time for all tabs I had opened. I believe they try to access the same counter value at once.

Comment: Now, I have a workaround for this as I put the listener for the very last tab's value. So it waits for that tab to load, modify the value and then trigger the events in my main tab.

Comment: My original problem is solved. Though, I ran into a problem of handling the access of a value from multiple instances of a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) in the sender tab to send a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) (when data is updated) and `addEventListener` in the target tab to listen for that event.